# Facing issue with indexPathsForVisibleRows in cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am displaying images from url in a `UITableView` and using `SDWebImage` for caching and it is working as expected. The only issue i am facing now is while downloading the image while scrolling the UITableView very fast, while scrolling at some point the if condition where i am checking for visibleRows is getting failed and hence reloading the specific cells after downloading the image is not happening so the cell is showing the placeholder image. This is not happening with every image, the issue is only observed for couple of images while scrolling fast, there is no issue with image urls, same images are loaded again if i scroll back and forth. Since the `cellForRowAt` is loaded before the cell is being visible so the condition is getting failed. How to make sure that the condition does not fail when we are scrolling fast

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell) as? TableViewCell else {
        // fall back code
    }
    
    //code to get the url from userData object
    let imageUrl = userData.imagePath
    //if the image is not in the cache download it
    guard let _ = SDImageCache.shared.diskImageData(forKey: imageUrl) else {
        if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
            SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared.prefetchURLs([url], progress: nil) { [weak self] (_, _) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                // i am facing using with this if condition sometimes the if condition is returning false
                if let visibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, visibleRows.contains(indexPath) {
                    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                }
            }
        }
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell
    }
}
```

I am setting the image inside `CustomTableViewCell` so i just need to trigger the reloadRows so that the downloaded image will be shown.

**Note:**    No issues with the code in `CustomTableViewCell`, the issue is only with the if condition inside the `cellForRowAt`, if i remove the if condition then it is working fine and able to see all images properly but reloading non-visible cells can impact performance.

**Tried below Solutions**

- Running the code in Main Thread
- Adding the code in `willDisplay cell:`

Nothing worked, Need a solution to avoid the condition getting failed. Any inputs will be really appreciated.

Comment: why you don't use from: cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url),
                         placeholderImage: UIImage(named: yourPlaceholderImage))

Comment: IMO your code is not correct, I think reload a tableviewrow again call the cellforrow at index, It causes a loop and in fast action, it(the issue) shows, can you show the cell design?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar. I cannot use cell.imageView.sd_setImage(...) since i already have a legacy logic written in UITableViewCustomCell for showing the placeholder and i will not be able to change it. FYI, you can consider the UI as a plain ImageView placed inside the cell no major complications to it. As i have mentioned earlier, the image is not the issue, even while scrolling fast i can see all the images only 1 or 2 are not loading, the if condition is failing so i need a solution to fix it.

Comment: In my opinion, for fast scrolling, you don't want to limit to visible rows. Which rows are visible will change too fast. Consider prefetching https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching to populate your cache. Then maybe the cache will be loaded by the time you need it. Edit: my mistake. I see you're already prefetching. I think you should throw out the notion of using visible rows only. The delegate will ask for your row details when needed.

Comment: @Madhu - since you only posted *part* of your code, it is tough to help. One thing to note: if you call `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` and the row for **that `indexPath` is *not visible***, nothing happens. So there is no need to check `.indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Comment: I can't know about the line: self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none),
this row call again "cellforrowatindex" why don't you call your downloader in the cell and set it to image in the cell for example with a function with config?

Comment: The issue you are facing might be that you are only including visible cells and missing prepared cells. You could modify your if-statement to `if self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) != nil`. This method will return a cell only if it is either visible or prepared. Try this change.

Comment: @MaticOblak, agree with you the code was missing the prepared cells but i only want to update the cell when the cell is visible so that was the reason i have added the visiblecell check but this was causing issues so i have modified the if-statement as per your suggestion and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing seems to be that once the image is downloaded you only update the cells that are visible but not the cells that are prepared.

What you encounter for some cells is that a download gets triggered by `tableView:cellForRowAt` method. Then this cell gets off the screen (or remains off the screen) but is in so-called "prepared" state. Once a download is complete you do not update the cell because it is not visible. And when you scroll to the cell it does not get updated by `tableView:cellForRowAt` method because this method is not being called for prepared cells.

I can imagine there is only a small chance for this to occur and a pain to debug.

Fortunately you can detect both visible and prepared cells using `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` method. This method will not dequeue a cell nor do any other complex logic. It simply returns a cell that table view has registered as being either visible or prepared, otherwise `nil`.

Try the following to fix the issue:

```
if self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) != nil {
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` ... calling `.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` is simply ignored if the cell for that indexPath does not currently exist.

Comment: @DonMag Are you sure about that? In my experience a lot of things happen in the back as soon as you start reloading cells. For instance the table view will invalidate some cell height caching if you use automatic cell heights. It can easily show in anomalies such as scrollbar jumping around or sometimes even shifting the content.

Comment: Matic - take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/xVcQH7CD ... button above a table view ... each button tap will add a line to the string in `myData[4]` and call `tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)], with: .none)` ... if you scroll so that row is off-screen, you can tap-tap-tap away, and you'll see that `cellForRowAt` is not called. Of course, when you scroll back up so that row is visible, `cellForRowAt` *will* be called and the cell will be reloaded with its updated data.

Comment: @DonMag I can understand that `cellForRowAt` is not being called. I am challenging "calling `.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` is simply ignored". The whole call being "ignored" (or at least doing nothing) does not equal to not calling one of the methods. Or in other words; even if the `cellForRowAt` is not being called there are other things being called which can inconvenience you, therefore using that if-statement still makes sense.

Comment: From Apple's docs: **"Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row."** ... the fact that `cellForRowAt` is **not** called indicates that it is being ignored. I don't work for Apple, so I can't point to a line of code that says "if the row is not visible { return }" but, we can easily demonstrate that nothing is changing.

Comment: @DonMag You might be right. Hard to tell. I made this quick example though https://pastebin.com/rgxNfmnD. When I try it and click on a cell that reloads a cell off-screen above and I try to begin scrolling upwards the scroller jumps as expected due to invalidation of estimated row height. Commenting out the reload part removes the glitch. So I think something does indeed happen in my case. But regardless, you must be right.

Comment: The implementation of `estimatedHeightForRowAt` ***explicitly tells the table view*** to re-evaluate its content size on every change. In your example, **reloading a *visible* row** can cause the same "scroll indicator jumping." Minor changes to your example to demonstrate (reload selected row and additional logging) here:    https://pastebin.com/C1dU2mWC ... `estimatedHeightForRowAt` is called 100 times and we get lots of calls to `cellForItemAt` on every did select.

Comment: We're getting beyond appropriate use of comments here... I'm happy to continue in chat, if you wish...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255618/discussion-between-donmag-and-matic-oblak).

Comment: @DonMag, so you are suggesting that we can ignore the if condition and it does not make any difference?

Comment: @MaticOblak what do you say?

Comment: @Madhu - take a look at and run the sample code we put up on pastebin ... see for yourself.

Comment: @Madhu Even if the if-statement did nothing due to internal checks I would vote for being explicit and use the condition. But I think we have established that "did nothing" is not GENERALLY true. And even if it was generally true the behavior is not documented as such and may change in future version. But then again, if it works for you, I see no reason why not to remove the check.

Comment: @Madhu - bottom line (in my view) ... if you actually find some effect from calling `.reloadRows` on a non-existent row, then implement the `if` conditional. As a side note, for your specific case: I am only sort-of familiar with `SDWebImage`, but I am under the impression that is handled *without* the need to reload the cell, so I'm not sure why you're doing so to begin with.